# Another FPM instance seems to already listen on /run/php-fpm/www.sock

Tags: rhel, php

When I start `php-fpm` on a RHEL9.2 system I get the error

> Another FPM instance seems to already listen on /run/php-fpm/www.sock

- My php version is 8.0.30
- Every time I have to create `/run/php-fpm` on boot before I can start `php-fpm`, and after starting it I get this error.

If you need to see my php configuration file and other related configuration files, please reply in time!

The following is some of the key information output by the command `journalctl -xeu php-fpm.service`:

```
Mar 03 11:04:30 RHEL9-A php-fpm[3762]: [03-Mar-2024 11:04:30] WARNING: [pool www] ACL set, listen.owner = 'www' is ignored
Mar 03 11:04:30 RHEL9-A php-fpm[3762]: [03-Mar-2024 11:04:30] WARNING: [pool www] ACL set, listen.group = 'www' is ignored
Mar 03 11:04:30 RHEL9-A php-fpm[3762]: [03-Mar-2024 11:04:30] ERROR: Another FPM instance seems to already listen on /run/php-fpm/www.sock
Mar 03 11:04:30 RHEL9-A php-fpm[3762]: [03-Mar-2024 11:04:30] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
Mar 03 11:04:30 RHEL9-A systemd[1]: php-fpm.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=78/CONFIG
```

Comment: php-fpm seems to be already running.